# How to write a function in R to calculate the min/max difference between two dataframes?

Tags: r, for-loop, difference

I am having difficulty writing a function in R to accomplish what I need. I am separated by a few hundred kilometers from my usual sources of reference and am stuck on where to even begin to write this. It has been a few years since my last (brief) programming class and I am flummoxed on how to proceed.

I have two dataframes, X & Y. Each dataframe is structured with rows 1-80, and columns 1-999.

I want to write a function such that I take each value by column and calculate the difference with all other values in the same row within my second dataframe.  Once I have the calculated difference between all my values across dataframes, I need to select the minimum and maximum difference for each row.

Min/Max of `(Xcol1:Xcol999,r1:r999 – Ycol1:Ycol999,r1:r999 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- X - Y
plyr::ldply(1:nrow(df), function(x) data.frame(
                       min=min(df[x,], na.rm=T), 
                       max=max(df[x,], na.rm=T)))
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it did exactly what I needed it to! This saved me a lot of stress and time- especially while I am doing field work. Thanks again!